# Show in a tables two list with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my xml:

```
<volume>
    <cap>title 1</cap>
    <cap>title 2</cap>
    <cap>title 3</cap>
    <cap>title 4</cap>
    <cap>title 5</cap>

    <desc>desc 1</desc>
    <desc>desc 2</desc>
    <desc>desc 3</desc>
    <desc>desc 4</desc>
    <desc>desc 5</desc>
</volume>
```

I want to convert it usign xslt, the final result shoudl be this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>title 1</td>
<td>desc 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>title 2</td>
<td>desc 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
```

I have tryed this xslt code:

```
...
<table style="border:solid 1px;  width:500px; margin:auto;">
    <xsl:for-each select="cap">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="../desc[position()]"/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
...
```

but it doesn't work. Which is the correct way to get the *n-th* desc when i'm in the *n-th* cap?

Comment: _"I have tryed many times,"_ >> please show _what_ you tried, so we can actually help you: [mcve].

Comment: i have added my code

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update to your question.

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="../desc[position()]"/>
> ```

Your idea is correct, except that `position()` here takes the position of `desc`, which is 1, 2, 3 etc, depending on the position of `desc` (the focus changes on each predicate test). A test like that is always true, because if the predicate contains a numeric value `$X`, it is short for `$X = position()`. In this case, you are actually writing `../desc[position() = position()]`, which is always true.

What you want is the current position of `cap`. To fix this, use a variable, as can be seen below.

Here's how I would do it, using XSLT's power with template matching:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" />

<xsl:attribute-set name="td1">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:attribute-set name="td2">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:template match="/volume">
    <table style="border:solid 1px;  width:500px; margin:auto;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cap" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cap">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
        <td xsl:use-attribute-sets="td1">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <br />
        </td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../desc[$pos]" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="desc">
    <td xsl:use-attribute-sets="td2">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
         <br />
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: after your update of your question, I added the dealings with the style attribute, and appended the `<tr>` element. Result is now, given your input:

```
<table style="border:solid 1px;  width:500px; margin:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">title 1<br></td>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">desc 1<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">title 2<br></td>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">desc 2<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">title 3<br></td>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">desc 3<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">title 4<br></td>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">desc 4<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; border-right:solid 1px; text-align:right; width:46%;">title 5<br></td>
    <td style="border-top: dotted 1px; text-align:right; :46%;">desc 5<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where do i put <tr> and <table> tag?

Comment: @user135755: I think you need to refresh the page or my answer, I updated it to reflect what you did in your code. Both are now there.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i was using variables wrong, now it works!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works now. In your example, you didn't use variables at all, but perhaps you refer to an earlier attempt not shown here?